# Conjugate upto isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $V= \{1,2,3,\cdots, n\}$ is a vertex set and Sym$(V)$ is a symmetric group. Let $G \le $ Sym$(V)$, i.e. subgroup of Sym$(V)$. Now

$$H= Sym(V_0^{\sigma}) \times Sym(V_1^{\sigma}) \cdots \times Sym(V_n^{\sigma}) $$

where $\sigma \in$ Sym$(V)$ and $V_i$ means set of vertices of degree $i.$

My question : What is a relationship between $G$ and $\sigma^{-1}H\sigma$ ? To me it appears that they are conjugate to each other upto isomorphism.

Second question : Is it true that $x^g = x^{\sigma^{-1}g_1 \sigma}$, where $g \in G$ and $g_1 \in H$ ?

Comment: Does $V_i^\sigma$ mean the set of elements of $V_i$ fixed by $\sigma$?

Comment: let $V_i = {v_1,v_2....v_k}$ then compute $V_i^{\sigma}$ and then Sym$(V_i^{\sigma})$ and $V_i^{\sigma}$ does not mean set of elements of $V_i$ fixed by $\sigma$

Comment: You say "then compute $V_i^\sigma$," but what does $V_i^\sigma$ **mean**?

Comment: Well, then what does $V_i^\sigma$ mean then?

Comment: This is not defined in the text I am reading.

Comment: You can't do the problem without knowing what the terms mean. (And neither can we.) Also, if it's not defined (as far as you know), what makes you say my interpretation of $V_i^\sigma$ as the fixed point set of $\sigma$ is wrong? Please tell us what text you are reading and where this is in it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59712/discussion-between-ram-and-arctic-tern).

Answer (score 0):

In chat you explain that $V_i^{\sigma}$ is supposed to be the image of $V_i$ under the function $\sigma_i$. This is contrary to standard notation in the context of group actions: the standard notation is $gX$ for the image of $X$ under $g$, and $X^g$ for the set of fixed points of $g$ in $X$.

The question is nonsense without saying what $G$ is. Indeed, the obvious interpretation is to say $G$ is the automorphism group of the graph. ($V$ is the vertex set of some graph.)

In this case, since graph automorphisms preserve vertex degree, we must have

$$ G\subseteq \mathrm{Sym}(V_0)\times\mathrm{Sym}(V_1)\times\cdots\times\mathrm{Sym}(V_n)\subseteq\mathrm{Sym}(V) $$

where the product is internal (so $\mathrm{Sym}(V_i)$ is the subgroup of $\mathrm{Sym}(V)$ of permutations whose support is contained in the complement $V\setminus V_i$).

Then

$$ \begin{array}{lcccccccc} H & = &  \mathrm{Sym}(\sigma V_0)~ & \times &  \mathrm{Sym}(\sigma V_1)~ & \times & \cdots & \times & \mathrm{Sym}(\sigma V_n)~ \\ & = & \sigma \mathrm{Sym}(V_0)\sigma^{-1} & \times & \sigma\mathrm{Sym}(V_1)\sigma^{-1} & \times & \cdots & \times & \sigma\mathrm{Sym}(V_n)\sigma^{-1} \end{array} $$

$$ =\sigma\big(\,\mathrm{Sym}(V_0)\times\mathrm{Sym}(V_1)\times\cdots\times\mathrm{Sym}(V_n)\, \big)\sigma^{-1} $$

contains $\sigma G\sigma^{-1}$. This containment follows from conjugating $G\subseteq\prod_i \mathrm{Sym}(V_i)$ by $\sigma$.

Note the containment is proper unless $G=\prod_i\mathrm{Sym}(V_i)$, which pretty much never happens.